# pass arguments to subprocess as command line arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I have an executable (test.exe) that takes command line arguments (for example, name and the filename):

```
./test.exe
```

So I if enter *Mike* and *word.docx* in the terminal, the executable will print out how many times that *Mike* are found in the document *word.docx*. Is there a way that I can write a loop in Python (probably with subprocess) that *test.exe* can search a list of the names and a list of documents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by writing the arguments into a txt file (input.txt) and the use subprocess as

```
subprocess.call('./test.exe < ./input.txt',shell=True)
```